# How to play videos in wpf (https://view.vzaar.com/821466.flashplayer)

Tags: wpf

I am new to wpf and I want to play videos in a wpf application. I tried Media Element in wpf, but throwing error. I am not sure webbrowser is the right choice. I want to display application in windows service.

```
  <MediaElement VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="
  https://view.vzaar.com/821466.flashplayer"
  Name="myMediaElement" Height="350" 
  Width="640" />
```

Comment: I suggest that you publish the error, if you want other users to help you solve it.

Comment: Whenever you need to find out something about a particular class, just go to MSDN instead of wasting your time asking here. You can get immediate answers to your questions from the [MediaElement Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WPF, but I am with vzaar (I'm the CTO)

I think where you're going wrong is the https://view.vzaar.com/821466/flashplayer bit. This will attempt to open a full flash player SWF. I'm not sure if this is what MediaElement.Source can handle.

If you instead use the URI for the video itself (e.g. https://view.vzaar.com/821466/video) and poster frame e.g. (https://view.vzaar.com/821466/image), this should work better.

Any other issues I suggest you raise a ticket on vzaar.com/help and our engineers can assist you more easily.

Adrian

Comment: I have tried with webbrowser in wpf and it worked. Thank U for your response

Comment: Excellant. Good to hear it.